# Which Windows 8 partition should I use?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu as a second operating system, and GRUB found two Windows 8 boot partitions (one of them is 350MB, which was reserved by Windows, and another where I installed Windows). Which of these partitions is more correct to use for booting Windows?

Comment: pease indicate your Boot-Info URL ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info )

Answer (score 0):

The smaller partition carries the bootloader of Windows. So choose the 350 MB partition.

[Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-za/windows-vista/what-are-system-partitions-and-boot-partitions) are some details by Microsoft. Maybe the *Disk Management* tool also shows which partition is the boot partition.